Filter table as per the multiple dropdown in cascade
I have multiple dropdown selects in cascade filtering data for a datatable.
sede(not binded),  escuela (loads) > curso (loads) > version.

My query in PostgreSql has no problem processing the four dropdown values. It brings the results expected.
The problem arises when I want to filter only by 1 or 2 or 3 selects out of 4, it brings nothing since the query only processes 4 values, it doesn't accepts  null or empty values.
Here is my Postgres query:
                     DB::SELECT("SELECT DISTINCT
                                ced_inscripcion.cein_rut AS Rut,
                                antecedentes_alumnos.anta_nombres AS Nombre,
                                antecedentes_alumnos.anta_paterno AS Apellido,
                                ced_inscripcion.cein_estado AS Estado,
                                escuelas.esc_descripcion AS Escuela,
                                ced_cursos.cecu_nombre AS Curso,
                                sedes.sede_nombre AS Sede,
                                antecedentes_alumnos.anta_fono1 Telefono, 
                                antecedentes_alumnos.anta_telefono_emergencia Telefono_eme,  
                                antecedentes_alumnos.anta_e_mail Correo,
                                ced_inscripcion.cein_fecha_inscripcion AS Fecha_Inscripcion
                            FROM ced_inscripcion
                            RIGHT JOIN 
                                ea_antecedentes ON ced_inscripcion.cein_rut = ea_antecedentes.eaa_rut 
                            INNER JOIN
                                antecedentes_alumnos ON ea_antecedentes.eaa_rut = antecedentes_alumnos.anta_rut
                            LEFT JOIN 
                                alumnos ON antecedentes_alumnos.anta_rut = alumnos.alum_antalu_rut
                            LEFT JOIN 
                                sedes ON alumnos.alum_cod_sede = sedes.sede_codigo 
                            INNER JOIN 
                                ced_cursos ON ced_inscripcion.cein_cecu_codigo = ced_cursos.cecu_codigo 
                            INNER JOIN 
                                escuelas ON ced_cursos.cecu_esc_codigo = escuelas.esc_codigo
                            WHERE
                                 sedes.sede_codigo = COALESCE(:sede,0)  
                            AND 
                                 escuelas.esc_codigo = COALESCE(:escuela,0)  
                            AND        
                                 ced_inscripcion.cein_cecu_codigo = COALESCE(:curso,0)  
                            AND
                                ced_inscripcion.cein_cvcu_version = COALESCE(:version,0)",
                                
                                ['version'=>$version, 'curso' =>$curso, 'sede'=>$sede, 'escuela' =>$escuela]
                            );
                           

How can I make the AND operator inside the query conditional ?
So it process and brings results for example using,
  sede = 2, escuela = 4, curso = NULL, version = NULL 

Thanks in Advance!

Please note that you may not get any results when selecting certain filters because the final query includes 'sede = 2' and 'curso = null', which may not match any records based on the selected filter values. You need to exclude the values that are not selected from the query. Here is the updated version for you. or you can get an idea from that
$bindings = [];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT
    ced_inscripcion.cein_rut AS Rut,
    antecedentes_alumnos.anta_nombres AS Nombre,
    antecedentes_alumnos.anta_paterno AS Apellido,
    ced_inscripcion.cein_estado AS Estado,
    escuelas.esc_descripcion AS Escuela,
    ced_cursos.cecu_nombre AS Curso,
    sedes.sede_nombre AS Sede,
    antecedentes_alumnos.anta_fono1 Telefono, 
    antecedentes_alumnos.anta_telefono_emergencia Telefono_eme,  
    antecedentes_alumnos.anta_e_mail Correo,
    ced_inscripcion.cein_fecha_inscripcion AS Fecha_Inscripcion
FROM ced_inscripcion
RIGHT JOIN 
    ea_antecedentes ON ced_inscripcion.cein_rut = ea_antecedentes.eaa_rut 
INNER JOIN
    antecedentes_alumnos ON ea_antecedentes.eaa_rut = antecedentes_alumnos.anta_rut
LEFT JOIN 
    alumnos ON antecedentes_alumnos.anta_rut = alumnos.alum_antalu_rut
LEFT JOIN 
    sedes ON alumnos.alum_cod_sede = sedes.sede_codigo 
INNER JOIN 
    ced_cursos ON ced_inscripcion.cein_cecu_codigo = ced_cursos.cecu_codigo 
INNER JOIN 
    escuelas ON ced_cursos.cecu_esc_codigo = escuelas.esc_codigo
    WHERE  1=1 ";

if($sede != NULL){
    $query .= " AND sedes.sede_codigo = :sede ";
    $bindings['sede'] = $sede;
}
if($escuela != NULL){
    $query .= " AND escuelas.esc_codigo = :escuela ";
    $bindings['escuela'] = $escuela;

}
if($curso != NULL){
    $query .= " AND ced_inscripcion.cein_cecu_codigo = :curso ";
    $bindings['curso'] = $curso;
}
if($version != NULL){
    $query .= " AND ced_inscripcion.cein_cvcu_version = :version ";
    $bindings['version'] = $version;
}
DB::SELECT($query, $bindings);


I made some adjustements and at last it worked, you missed the AND operator on every query, see your solution working https://youtu.be/PvM3soaoHkc

Found a little bug, when I press the filter button with no dropdown selected it fails, I put 1=1 back after WHERE and it works (brings all records) only in this situation. but fails when selecting any  of the 4 dropdown.

@RodrigoCabrera, I added 1=1 because then we don't need to decide whether it is the first clause or the second clause to use "AND" or "WHERE". I also added a space before "AND" so that during concatenation there should be a space to avoid a syntax error.

I've rewritten your existing query  in my answer to eliminate any unnecessary filters.

RIght, I missed the space and the first AND, it works perfectly!

Your current approach is if a parameter wasn't set, you pass a zero instead, which produces a mismatch on the condition the param was responsible for. To flip that and make a missing param just cancel the condition, wrap it in parentheses and add an or :param is null - that way the combined conditions will evaluate to true that doesn't break your sequence of AND.
WHERE (sedes.sede_codigo is not distinct from :sede 
       or :sede is null)
  AND (escuelas.esc_codigo is not distinct from :escuela 
       or :escuela is null)
  AND (ced_inscripcion.cein_cecu_codigo is not distinct from :curso 
       or :cursor is null)
  AND (ced_inscripcion.cein_cvcu_version is not distinct from :version 
       or :version is null)

You can also use is not distinct from x comparison instead of =coalesce(x,y) to be able to actually look up records where the table really does hold null values in the target field. Here it's ORd with true in that case anyways, but the construct is worth mentioning.

I tried your solution, but it doesn't load the info in the datatable when I only select two dropdown filters, I created a youtube video portraying what happens https://youtu.be/gUAOLDp4LZY

@RodrigoCabrera It does work, you can test it here. Maybe something along the way swaps out the null values for empty strings '' or text constants with a literal, four-letter 'null' string.

If either of these was the case, you could try to change it like this or like this and see if that changes anything.

Or you can set up a query like this, pass your parameters and see what it says. It should tell you what the database actually received from your front end.
